# Has kin selection enabled the evolution of interspecial communication?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, communication, anthropology, signalling

I know animals often imitate specific behaviour (like when they show their teeth to evoke "danger!" in the reciever) as a form of communication. Although, for a fully-fledged language where we can express *anything we can think of* to develop, we need more complicated signals.

And for that, we need both the reciever and the signaler to understand the same signalling system. And since for a language as complex, the animals need to share a lot of similar "associations" with similar signals - it's good when the communicating animals orientate a similar environment - such as siblings.

Is this a possible explanation of the evolution of language?

I know the signalling theory is a biological branch on its own, however I seem not to be able to come up with an alternative explanation. Also, I know that this kind of group selection is sometimes used to explain the evolution of altruism. So is this how the evolution of communication happens?

Comment: Perhaps better asked on Linguistics.SE?

Comment: @anongoodnurse If my hypothesis is true, it applies on all kinds of complex communication systems.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Also I was mindblown when I realized that this had to be minimally the way altruism has evolved.

Comment: I don't know about this.  I manage to communicate fairly well with my dogs and horses, and they with me.

Comment: @jamesqf They've learned that if they'll respond in certain wain on certain stimuli, they'll got some reward. The problem occurs when we notice that the relationships among animals don't often work that way. Similar ideas are discussed in the book [The evolution of language](http://www.genlingnw.ru/board/attachments/fitch_evolution.pdf)

Comment: @Probably: But they've also learned that if they direct certain stimuli to me, I will (generally) respond in certain ways, which will get them what they want. That's certainly communication, isn't it?

Comment: @jamesqf I think it's the same case - they learn certain behavior to get rewards. But when you signal to your collegue an information about a bear standing behind him, it's an "altruistic" behavior because when the bear isn't after you specifically, you got some time to run while the bear is chewing your collegue. And, of course, it turns out not to be altruistic considering everyone would have done that in your situation. But this situation occurs only if someone goes first with to "try" if altruism pays of - and of course, since he's the only one, his DNA won't be passed on.

Comment: So for altruistic behaviour you need the population to evolve this mutation at the same time. And evolution of such trait within a family seemed like a nice explanaiton for me, even though there are certainly ways to avoid that - if the animals interact in the means of the theory of games, they could have evolved altruistic genes as well.

Comment: @Probably: Well, all of language is just behavior learned to get rewards (or to avoid punishment).  As for altruism, your example (like most supposed altruism) is really just an example of forward thinking.  That is, by warning the colleague, you trade a small risk that the bear will catch you instead of him for the large potential benefit that he may provide you in the future.

Comment: @jamesqf Sure, my point was that being the "first altruist" doesn't pay of. Of course, everything we do is driven by endorphines but it's a different kind of reward system when there's not just stimulus-reflex behaviour

Comment: You're probably right to say that, neurologically speaking, there's no difference between the "rationally learned" and "stimulus-reflex" behaviour   (even though some consider the border to be The theory of mind). The difference important for our case is that it doesn't pay to be the "first altruist" but it pays for your horses to listen to you (and that's not even a "rationally learned" behavior btw since they're domesticated)

Comment: You're probably right to say that, neurologically speaking, there's no difference between the "rationally learned" and "stimulus-reflex" behaviour   (even though some consider the border to be The theory of mind). The difference important for our case is that it doesn't pay to be the "first altruist" but it pays for your horses to listen to you (and that's not even a "rationally learned" behavior btw since they're domesticated)

Comment: @Probably: But it often does pay to be the first altruist, as long as you don't invest too much in the altruistic act.  Further, I'm not sure that I buy into the idea that there's a difference in kind between "stimulus-response" and "rationally learned".  And endorphins are a result, not a cause, though of course they can establish a feedback cycle.

Comment: @jamesqf Well, apart from establishing a feedback cycle, I had on mind the neurotransmiters neurons use in a similar way to navigate new paths as well. But about the difference between "stimulus-response" and "rationally learned": you're right, phisiologucally, it's just about the level of complexity of communication but your horses are domesticated so there might be an evolutionary predisposition to listen to you - basically all behavior in smaller mamalls is driven by evolution.

Comment: The selective pressure towards cooperation can occur only once they've got an advantage when they start cooperating. Otherwise, you would have to assume group selection for altruistic behavior, which is not accepted among biologists.

Comment: @Probably We are starting a Bioacoustics Stack Exchange for people interested in the studies of non-human animal sounds and the impacts of sounds on animals. Please join us! https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126698/bioacoustics?referrer=YjZmYjUxYzJkNDI1YmY5NDk3NzdhMzViMmZlNzI4ZDdiYTAyMWQxNTM5ZWFiNzRhODNkMmFiMzIxZjI3MmY1N_gFvrICTvBsmYNJ2ptRM6lIZEAV-VGkXtIwNyVDja680